# evaluation function in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to do the following:

```
SQL> select 1>2 from dual;
select 1>2 from dual
        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

But these are OK

```
SQL> select 1 from dual;

     1
----------
     1

SQL> select 2*3 from dual;

       2*3
----------
     6
```

How to ask Oracle to evaluate `1>2` in a simple way (without writing a separate PL/SQL function)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is a boolean.  Try this:

```
select (case when 1>2 then 1 else 0 end)
from dual
```

Oracle does not treat booleans as if they were numbers